# How to extract the ip address from a url

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a config file whose contents are as follows:

```
db.path=/home/kpmg/test/dbfiles/dbone.db
db.connection.timeout=500000
server.url=http://a.b.c.d:8033/plain/httpds?
output.file.path=/home/kpmg/test/dbfiles/
log.file.path=/home/kpmg/test/dbfiles/
log.level=DEBUG
```

I need to extract just the ip address from the `server.url` line. I did try using several awk commands by reading examples and documentation but unable to get it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way with `awk` to print just the IP:

```
$ awk -F'[/:]' '/server[.]url/{print $4}' file
a.b.c.d
```

Or using `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=server.url=http://)[^:]*' file
a.b.c.d
```

Or just `grep` for IP's:

```
$ egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'http://|:[0-9]+' '$0=$2' file
```

this works for your example:

```
kent$  echo "db.path=/home/kpmg/test/dbfiles/dbone.db
db.connection.timeout=500000
server.url=http://a.b.c.d:8033/plain/httpds?
output.file.path=/home/kpmg/test/dbfiles/
log.file.path=/home/kpmg/test/dbfiles/
log.level=DEBUG"|awk -F'http://|:[0-9]+' '$0=$2'
a.b.c.d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${URL}" | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Here is the gist which tests against various possibilities: https://gist.github.com/leodotcloud/c4cbedaabeba0a06956188a04022e9ce

Sample run:

```
# ./get_domain_from_url.sh
For URL:http://1.1.1.1, domain name:1.1.1.1
For URL:http://1.1.1.1:8443, domain name:1.1.1.1
For URL:https://1.1.1.1, domain name:1.1.1.1
For URL:https://1.1.1.1:8443, domain name:1.1.1.1
For URL:http://hello-world, domain name:hello-world
For URL:http://hello-world.com, domain name:hello-world.com
For URL:http://sub.hello-world.com, domain name:sub.hello-world.com
For URL:http://hello-world:8080, domain name:hello-world
For URL:http://hello-world.com:8080, domain name:hello-world.com
For URL:http://sub.hello-world.com:8080, domain name:sub.hello-world.com
For URL:https://hello-word/foo/bar, domain name:hello-word
```